# Multiple values with Drupal Embedded Media Field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am a novice programming and I met this problem which I have not been able to figure out. Hope that you can help me out.

I am currently using Drupal 6.20 with the Embedded media field (http://drupal.org/project/emfield). I have added an Embedded Video field into a content type named Video-Post. I set the value of "Number of Values" as "Unlimited" at .../admin/content/node-type/video-post

When I proceed to create a new node for content type Video Post at .../node/add/video-post, I see 2 "Embed a video" fields (despite me not yet clicking on the "Add another item button") and a "Add another item" button.

I would like it to show only 1 "Embed a video" field even when I set the "Number of Values" as "Unlimited".

Which file and function should I modify to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the module I'm going to say you may be able to use form_alter() to modify the output.

Comment: I was thinking it is a bug with the embed field module. I suppose it uses CONTENT_HANDLE_CORE to deal with multiple values. Any idea where the bug may be at?